Can't ping 8.8.8.8
I have an Ubuntu server which is running fine, but recently it can't ping 8.8.8.8. It just returns Network not reachable. What's happening here? I am behind an Xfinity gateway.
Here is a screenshot:

These are the results running journalctl -xu systemd-networkd.service :








Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You have nameserver with address 127.0.0.53. To make pingable 8.8.8.8 you need to change dns accordinally.
The first way to do it:

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
Change nameserver 127.0.0.53 to nameserver 8.8.8.8
Run sudo resolvectl status
Reboot machine

The other way to achieve the same result:

ls /etc/netplan/ to check full name of .yaml file
sudo nano /etc/netplan/{filename}.yaml
Change row addresses in nameservers section: addresses: [whatever adresses here] to addresses: [8.8.8.8]
sudo netplan apply


This is not the problem nor the solution.
